Google Auth Token expiration and unable to refresh auth token automatically
Google Auth Token expiration and unable to refresh auth token automatically
We are using Google Library API to fetch photos from Users Google Library to a custom app.
The current issue is , after a while like over period of 24 hrs, the signed in google user session expires and then unable to get photos automatically from Library API
Basically trying to figure out auto refresh of auth token with our user consent again.
This app runs photos in a scoll mode and hence should never ask user consent again once logged in with google account.
Can you point us to right resuources to implement auto refresh of auth tokens without user intervention again.
